# I am trying to convert Salesforce data to XML tags. End goal is to be able to import into MS Project. This will make the job of operations team easier

Tags: apex, force.com, xml

So our operations team usually works on MS Project to manage our Projects, tasks,milestones, timelines and status. However, we also have a custom built solution on Salesforce for the same purpose. Now, I am trying to build a solution to import Salesforce data and present it in the format of MS Project.

My Approach -

1. Opened an MS Project file and saved it as XML. Saved the extract XML file.
2. I am able to import the file I got from step 1 into MS Project file.
3. Now, I want to export Salesforce records also into the same format and generate an XML (similar to step 1).
4. I could use it to import into MS Project

**challenges** I see with accomplishing step 3 are

1. Our XML file could be as big as 20MB, maybe more as well. Can I still be able to generate the file using XMLStreamReader and XMLStreamWriter?
2. Do you suggest any alternate approach apart from the one I described above?

Please advise.

Comment: That's going to be a lot of work.  And once you export a project's data, what happens if someone makes a change in Salesforce?  How will you copy that changed data into the existing MS Project file?

Comment: They are more likely to make the changes on MS Project, than Salesforce. So, when the data goes into Salesforce, it will usually be in good shape and probably few changes will need to be made. 

Background : Our users have been using MS Project for many years to manage the operations of their Projects (Operations Management). We also have an application built for the same purpose (Operations Management) on Salesforce. Since MS Project is more suited for the purpose, users still use it as the main thing, while Salesforce is used for better reporting abilities.

Answer (score 0):

> Our XML file could be as big as 20MB, maybe more as well. Can I still be able to generate the file using XMLStreamReader and XMLStreamWriter?

No, that's going to be a deal-breaker. The easiest way to run code, synchronously, is limited to 6MB of heap. You'll run out way before you hit 20MB. The slightly more complicated method, asynchronous, will only get you to 12MB.

> Do you suggest any alternate approach apart from the one I described above?

JavaScript! Write your solution in Aura or LWC. Have it fetch the data, in chunks, if necessary, then build the XML on the client. The client-side code can create an [Object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static) or a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs), then use the `a` element to trigger a download, such as:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = urlToDownload;
a.download = 'filename-to-suggest';
a.click();
```